# How to access an options menu item from outside the menu

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-optionsmenu

How can an options menu item be accessed from an object outside of the menu itself? I'm trying to set an alpha value for one of the options menu items, but it's not working for some reason. The commented lines are what I tried.

I've seen the following code used before, but it's not clear on where and how it should be used:

```
    Drawable drawable = item.getIcon();
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.mutate();
        drawable.setAlpha(1);
    }
```

**Activity class**

```
public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = WebviewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    WebView myWebView;
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_webview);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_webview);

        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                myProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });
    }

    private class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
            String url=request.getUrl().toString();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

    public void onBtnBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void onBtnForwardPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoForward()){
            myWebView.goForward();
        } else {
//            menu.getItem(R.id.action_webbrowser_forward).setEnabled(false);
//            menu.getItem(R.id.action_webbrowser_forward).mutate();
//            menu.getItem(R.id.action_webbrowser_forward).setAlpha(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.web_browser, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_webbrowser_back) {
            onBtnBackPressed();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_webbrowser_forward) {
            onBtnForwardPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define in your activity class this variable:

```
MenuItem action_webbrowser_forward;
```

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` after the inflation of the menu, write this:

```
action_webbrowser_forward = menu.findItem(R.id.action_webbrowser_forward);
```

then you can use it anywhere in your class:

```
action_webbrowser_forward.setEnabled(false);
```

**but** `mutate` is used for drawables and not menu items, so get the icon of the item by `action_webbrowser_forward.getIcon()` and apply mutate to it.

Comment: Is there something else other than  `mutate` that can be used to change the alpha of menu items?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'action_webbrowser_forward' when I wrote this in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: What is `menuItemForward`? In your code you have `R.id.action_webbrowser_forward`

Comment: I meant `action_webbrowser_forward`

Comment: This `MenuItem action_webbrowser_forward;` must be placed at your class level, under these definitions:     WebView myWebView;    ProgressBar myProgressBar;

Comment: Okay, but it's a huge shame that I still can't set the alpha.

Comment: I guess you can do it for the icon if you get it.

Comment: The menu item is actually using an XML icon

Comment: Try this: `action_webbrowser_forward.getIcon().setAlpha(0.5f);`

Comment: `setAlpha()` requires API level 19

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `MenuItem` reference on your `onBtnForwardPressed` function parameters :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_webbrowser_back) {
            onBtnBackPressed();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_webbrowser_forward) {
            onBtnForwardPressed(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And :

```
public void onBtnForwardPressed(MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (myWebView.canGoForward()){
            myWebView.goForward();
        } else {
            menuItem.setEnabled(false);
            menuItem.getIcon().setAlpha(50);

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Okay I spend couple of hour to get this solution.apparently you can get menuitem from your toolbar. So in my case.

```
var menuItem = toolbar.menu;
```

Now to get specfic item from menu item

```
favIcon = menuItem.findItem(R.id.favourite);
```

**Note**: favIcon is MenuItem declare global
Now if you can do whatever you want to do for this icon
eg. to make it invisible

```
favIcon?.isVisible=false
```

Comment: I spent way too long on this because of the new `MenuProvider`. This saved me so much headache thank you.